# Find class property by Attribute value

Tags: c#, .net

I want to find a class property by its attribute and attribute value.

Given this attribute and class:

```
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


class MyClass
{
    [MyAttribute("Something1")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [MyAttribute("Something2")]
    public string Description { get; set; } 
}
```

I know I can find specific attributes like this:

```
var c = new MyClass();
var props = c.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(MyAttribute)));
```

But how can I filter for attribute name value "Something2"?

So my final goal is to output "MyClass.Description" by searching for attribute MyAttribute with value "Something" in MyClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do somenthing like this

```
var c = new MyClass();
var props = c.GetType()
             .GetProperties()
             .Where(prop => prop.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                .OfType<MyAttribute>()
                                .Any(att => att.Name == "Something1"));
```

Comment: Just a note, the parameter to `GetCustomAttributes` is whether inherited attributes are searched. This value is **ignored** for properties. You'd have to use `Attribute.GetCustomAttributes` if you ever needed to do this in an inheritence hierarchy (abstract property for example)

Answer (score 2):

In an old foreach style

```
var c = new MyClass();
var props = c.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(MyAttribute)));

foreach (var prop in props)
{
    MyAttribute myAttr = (MyAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(MyAttribute));
    if (myAttr.Name == "Something2")
        break; //you got it
}
```